# Best way to keep TextArea updated?

Tags: java, swing, io

I am trying to write a simple chat app and am logging the messages in a file. Currently I am working on a GUI with Swing. I want the previous messages to be displayed in a TextArea, but I only know how to read from a file once, like this:

```
public void showMsgHistory() throws IOException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader( "persMsgHistory.txt" );
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    messageHistory.read(br, null);
}
```

What is the best way to keep this up to date? Should I use a Timer or is there a better approach?

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: A timer would be your easiest solution for sure.

Comment: If I were you, at load time I would populate the TextArea - textArea.setText(fullText), and then, whenever a new message is received/typed, firstly I would add the message in the TextArea.. textArea.append(newMessage); and then save it to the file as you do it right now

Comment: Can you make a non blocking thread? Once the file is updated the thread works to update the text. The timer is not an elegant solution and its a blocking thread nature

Comment: Thanks guys, I will stick to the Timer approach. I don't get the blocking thread thing, sorry :D